# Include hostgroups in nagios notifications

Tags: nagios

Im trying to include the hostgroups in my nagios notification. I modified the commands.cfg notify_host_by_email command to include

```
... Host: $HOSTNAME$\nHostgroups: $HOSTGROUPS$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$ ...
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I just get Hostgroups: $ in my email.
Does anyone know the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the current behavior is correct as you are trying to use invalid macro.
To get list of all supported Nagios macros see [this](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/macrolist.html) document.

You should use `$HOSTGROUPNAME$` instead of `$HOSTGROUPS$` or maybe `$HOSTGROUPNAMES$` if it is usual that your hosts belongs to multiple host groups.

Comment: Perfect. That Macro list is super helpful.